# No response after clicking button on JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

sorry for this very basic question.
So I want to know how to make buttons responsive.

I have a client.js and index.html as shown below

```js
// Function to change the content of t2
function modifyText() {
  const t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
  if (t2.firstChild.nodeValue == "three") {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "two";
  } else {
    t2.firstChild.nodeValue = "three";
  }
}

// Add event listener to table
const el = document.getElementById("myButton");
el.addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
```

```html
<table id="outside">
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
</table>
<button id="myButton">Click Me!</button>
```

When I run on codepen it works fine.
But when I try to run these locally, with a server.js like this

```
console.log('Server-side code running');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// serve files from the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// start the express web server listening on 8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('listening on 8080');
});

// serve the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

and I change the html into having a script calling the client.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Example-1</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
  <table id="outside">
  <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
  <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
  <script src="client.js"></script>
  </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Then I run `node server.js` and I type `localhost:8080` in my browser, the html file gets displayed but when I click the button, it doesn't cause any number changes.
How can I get these to work for real?

Also, ultimately I want the node.js server side to know a button has been pressed. Maybe print on the node.js console that "a button was pressed", whenever it was done on my browser. How can I achieve that?

What I want is to pass information from client side to server side easily but I am quite confused with how to do that and many people suggest different ways.

Edit:
Aligned file names.

Comment: what is content of `client_click.js` and is the file loaded correctly? for sending request to server you can use `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` or some library like axios

Comment: @Chris Li   Oops I edited and the source script to be run should be client.js at the start of the post.

Comment: check if you js actually loaded and ran, also move the script tag outside of table, not sure if its valid

Comment: @ChrisLi Ok I tested dragging the script tag out of the table, no difference. I don't know how to check if the js script called in html is actually loaded and run. Should I add some XMLHttpRequest in the client.js for it to talk to the server and some listener in the server and cause the server to receive the signal?

Comment: Can you show an image of the project structure? I have a feeling it might be related to that. You can confirm from the browser developer tools if the client.js call is returning 404 and if that's the case, you might need to provide an absolute path to express.static using the `path` module. e.g `app.use(express.static(path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), 'public')));`. Seeing your project structure would really help.

Comment: @Daisi Sowemimo  Hey thanks for your willingness to help! Checked the browser dev tools and found "Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/client.js”. localhost:8080:14:1
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/client.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."
For the project structure, 1st level: I have one large project folder named "node test"; 2nd level: one "myfirstreactapp" folder, one "node_modules" folder, and some files in the same level. The files of this level include client.js, index.html, and server.js.

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo In Chrome, they give another error message which is "GET http://localhost:8080/client.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @AlgoManiac from what you're saying, it doesn't seem the client.js file is in a public folder. The directory you're pointing to in the express.static function seems to be incorrect, that's all. If you put the client.js file in a directory called public and then test it. Should be fine.

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo What does it mean by public folder? The client.js is just contained within the "nodetest" project folder, without being enclosed inside some other folder. How do I put it in a public folder to be found? Also why Chrome gives different error than Firefox, it seems Firefox could find it?

Comment: @AlgoManiac the argument you're passing to `express.static` is actually the location/directory where you place static files you want to be served. Within the nodetest folder, simply create another folder named `public` and place the client.js file there and you should be fine. 

Express works with middleware going from top to bottom so when a network call is made to your server requesting `client.js`, it will first hit the middleware returned from the express.static function which means it's going to look for client.js in the public folder which you stated when calling express.static

Comment: @AlgoManiac the folder name could have been called anything. If you created a folder and named it `assets` then you would use the code `express.static('assets')`. It's just telling express look in this folder for the file and if found return it else just go to the next middleware. The important thing to know is that you're telling express to look for some files in a folder so the folder has to exist and the file also has to be in the folder otherwise you get a 404 because it cannot find it. Hope this explanation helps :)

Comment: @DaisiSowemimo Thanks for your help. It is working now! Do you know how I can let the server know I clicked the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246551/discussion-between-daisi-sowemimo-and-algomaniac).